# Can I install xlwings via Cygwn rather than Windows-Native Python distribution?

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, python, cygwin

xlwings is an SQL support add-on for MS Excel which also requires a Python backend with a pip-installed xlwings package. See installation instructions [here](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/latest/installation.html). Now, on a Windows machine I'm working on, there's no Python distro installed directly, but Cygwin is installed, within which there's also a Python distro.

My question: Can I use xlwings with the Cygwin Python backend and installed package? Or do I need to install a second Pyton distribution?